# How to find the index of an array where the value is larger than some threshold in numpy?

Tags: python

In python (3.5.2) I have an increasing array of values, and I want to find the index at which the values become larger than some threshold.

I tried the following code

```
f = [0.0, 9.7, 19.5, 29.2, 39.0, 48.8, 58.5, 68.3, 78.1, 87.8, 97.6, 107.4, 117.1, 126.9]
index = min(np.argwhere(f>100))
```

which yields an error

```
TypeError: unorderable types: list() > int()
```

however, the expected outcome is `index=11`, as `f[11]` is the first element of the array `f` to be larger than 100.

How to fix this code? Is there a better way?

Comment: do np.array(f) insteaf of f

Comment: The error is because np.argwhere is expecting a numpy array, not a list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:

```
np.argwhere(np.array(f)>100).min()
```

Or:

```
np.argmax(np.array(f)>100)
```

Take note that [argmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) stops at first index that evaluates condition to `True`.

Comment: @yatu It will work, without scanning the whole array, only downside is that if no value meets the condition `argmax` returns `0`.